# Does parameter position matter in where clause of SQL Query

Tags: sql

```
Declare @temp As Int
set @temp = 10

select Column1 from MyTable where Column2 = @temp

select Column1 from MyTable where @temp = Column2
```

Is there any change in performance based on position of parameter in where clause.

Comment: No, there should be no change in performance.

Comment: You could see for yourself by viewing the *"explain / execution plan"* for each query

Comment: Thanks for your inputs :) I will test this again with execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no change. However, You can confirm this by running the execution plan in sql viewer.

Answer (score 0):

No, those two should be identical.